# SQL apply formula to AVG values

Tags: sql-server-2008

given the pseudo-table:

```
+-----+---------------------+------+
| tag | data                | read |
+-----+---------------------+------+
| A   | 2013-10-10 15:00:00 | 1345 |
+-----+---------------------+------+
| A   | 2013-10-10 15:15:00 | 3454 |
+-----+---------------------+------+
| A   | 2013-10-10 15:30:00 | 2345 |
+-----+---------------------+------+
| A   | 2013-10-10 15:45:00 | 1132 |
+-----+---------------------+------+
| B   | 2013-10-10 15:00:00 | 6234 |
+-----+---------------------+------+
| B   | 2013-10-10 15:15:00 | 5432 |
+-----+---------------------+------+
| B   | 2013-10-10 15:30:00 | 4563 |
+-----+---------------------+------+
| B   | 2013-10-10 15:45:00 | 5432 |
+-----+---------------------+------+
```

Is it possible to apply the following equation using SQL only?

Example:

```
result=AVG(A)-(AVG(B)+AVG(C))
```

or

```
result=AVG(A)+AVG(B)
```

grouped by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should calculate result

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85344/2/0).

```
select (AVG(case when tag = 'A' then read end) + AVG(case when tag = 'B' then read end)) 'result', data
from TBL
group by data
```

Comment: It works fine. BUT must remove "else 0" cause it will affect avg calculations so `... AVG(CASE WHEN tag='A' THEN read END)...`

Answer (score 0):

You can select a sum or avg for each tag individually and then select with the operation you want on each of those individual queries

```
select (select SUM([read]) from table where tag = 'A') + 
  (select SUM([read]) from table where tag = 'B')
```